# Gmsmapview long gesture release using PageViewControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need some help in getting one issue fixed with long gesture on marker to show another view.

The issue screen has GMSMap in pageview controller. It has been achieved by delegate method of GMSMap but it is not giving any response/release point of that delegate like UILongGestureStateCancelled or Ended.

I am getting the response in case i make custom change in long gesture on GMSMapView, but in this case i am facing another issue where in i am not able to drag the map and it show me the next screen.

P.S. I want to drag the map only.

****I have tried following code.****

```
 _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-65) camera:camera];
_mapView.delegate = self;
_mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
_mapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture
= [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = .5; //seconds

_mapView.gestureRecognizers = @[longPressGesture];
```

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks